# A copy of a.cpp was found in somepath, but the current source code is different from the version built into somepath

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This warning pops out in such scenario:

- Start debugging (F5) a C++ program
- Edit some code while debugging (the program hits a breakpoint and then pauses for example) [#]
- Stop debugging (Shift+F5) the program
- Start debugging (F5) again [*] ->  WARNING: but the current source code is different from the version

Actually in step [*], I would like to debug the code with modifications made in step [#]. However, Visual Studio is actually debugging the code without modifications made in step [#] and thus warns me about that.

I have to clean the project before step [*] to make Visual Studio be aware of my modifications made in step [#]. How could I make Visual Studio always debug my up-to-date source files?

Extra information: It's "Always Build" and the "Build" box is checked in Configuration Manager. Besides, in step [*], even I manually trigger "Build" (Ctrl+Shift+B), it says that my project is up-to-date. Actually my my project is out-of-date both in "Start Without Debugging" and "Start Debugging". I have to clean the project to make my project up-to-date.

**Video attached (2 mins), starting from "new project"**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y9RljtS28k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out by myself that it is a feature called `Edit and Continue`.

It's under `Tools - Options - Debugging - General - Enable Edit and Continue`

To apply code changes explicitly, on the `Debug` menu, choose `Apply Code Changes` [1].

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf.aspx#bkmk_how_to_apply_code_changes_explicitly

Answer (score 3):

You have to *rebuild* the application after you make changes to the code. You are launching an old version of your executable, which is out of sync with the most recent edits to the source code files. The debugger is detecting this, and warning you that you are subject to see invalid information if you break into the debugger during execution.

If Visual Studio is not prompting you to rebuild your project after you make a change (or if it's not doing it automatically), you have a setting misconfigured in your IDE. Visit Settings → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run, and make sure it is set to "Always Build", rather than "Never Build."

If that doesn't fix it, make sure that your project is set to build. Check the Configuration Manager (from the debug/release drop-down combobox in the toolbar), and make sure that the "Build" box is checked for both Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: Hi Cody, I have now attached a video (2 mins) starting from the very beginning: https://youtu.be/XuU6azPP_Qo

Comment: @zizheng The error message you get tells you everything you need to know. Look at the paths to the two code files, the first one it gives you compared to the second one. They are different. What's happened is, you've created a new, empty project, and then you've imported an existing code file into it. Which works, it imports a copy of that code file. The first time you compile, the two code files have identical contents, so everything works as expected. Then, you make a change to the *original* code file, stored in a different location, *not the copy that has been added to your project*.

Comment: When you rebuild the project to debug it, it doesn't detect that there have been any changes to the code files associated with the project---because there haven't. The fix is simple, make sure that you're editing the copy of the code file associated with the project. Open the file from the Solution Manager just to be sure.

Comment: Hi Cody, the paths in the warning message are the same and I believe I am editing the file from the solution manager. I just uploaded an even more straight-forward video (1080P to make the warning message readable) to illustrate my problem: https://youtu.be/0y9RljtS28k